# Difference between $\Rightarrow$, $\Longrightarrow$ and $\rightarrow$ in Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: proof-assistants, interactive-proof-systems, isabelle

I haven't been able to find a good explanation of how these are different and relate to each other. I know that $\to$ is part of HOL and $\Rightarrow$ and $\Longrightarrow$  part of Isabelle, but it seems that they are basically doing the same thing and we could just have one object $\to$? (Taking into account the CH correspondence). Why does Isabelle/HOL have 3 operators for essentially the same thing? How are they different?

Comment: For those interested in Proof Assistants, there is a new proposed SE site [ProofAssistants](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants?referrer=Njg4YTJmMjYwOTIxNjdkNGEyMmZkNzE0Y2M4YmFhOTY3OWVmNDUwNWM3ZmFlMjYwYTRiYzZiZWY1ODg5ZjdiMqfBIyhShuHO9QbGuJfVwOYRvfVgPfbJQrn2UOFTeOe-0)

Answer (score 3):

> I haven't been able to find a good explanation of how these are different and relate to each other. I know that → is part of HOL and ⇒ and ⟹ part of Isabelle, but it seems that they are basically doing the same thing and we could just have one object →? (Taking into account the CH correspondence).

The basic answer is because it depends on whether you want implication in the metalanguage ($\Longrightarrow$ or `==>`) or the object language (all other arrows), since Isabelle is a ["metalogical framework"](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/9301105) for reasoning within a specific "object logic".

Curry-Howard is relevant for the *metalogic*. If you try to use Curry-Howard with the object logic, you get an "object level" correspondence, which is already implicit in the object logic.

According to the [documentation](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/tutorial.pdf):

- $P\to Q$ (ascii `P --> Q`) is for "object language" logical implication "$P$ implies $Q$", i.e., implication in the object logic (encoding, e.g., implication in HOL); this is **not** part of the Isabelle's underlying "meta" logic;
- $\tau_{1}\Rightarrow\tau_{2}$ (ascii `tau => tau`) is used in Isabelle/HOL for the [total] function HOL type from HOL type $\tau_{1}$ to produce a HOL term of HOL type $\tau_{2}$;
- $\Longrightarrow$ (ascii `==>`) is the "meta-implication", i.e., the implication in the "metalogical framework" [i.e., the Pure language]. It's used for encoding "object logic" inference rules; if used for stating theorems, then those theorems may be used directly with forward or backward chaining (whereas theorems stated using `-->` needs to invoke implication inference rules), as [Paulson tells us](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2018-December/msg00031.html).

Really, you should use "$\Longrightarrow$" (`==>`) as much as possible when stating theorems. But there are times when you want to state *in the object logic* "$P$ implies $Q$"...and that requires "$\to$" (`-->`).

Further useful reading:

- [Taming meta implication in Isar proofs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25287976)
- Chapter 2 of Part I in the [Old Introduction to Isabelle](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021/doc/intro.pdf)
- For more on the technical fine points about "metalogical frameworks", the original paper [The Foundation of a Generic Theorem Prover](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/9301105) is worth reading

Comment: Thank you. And why do we have to make this distinction? For example, in Lean Peover there is no such distinction. There is only -> and it performs all functinalities.

Comment: Well, the Lean prover is not a metalogical framework, unlike Isabelle. The goal for having a metalogical framework is that you can "reason in any deductive system". That is to say, a metalogical framework effectively acts like a "functional core" for building a theorem prover (which is why you have Isabelle/X, where X = HOL or ZF or ...). You could have Isabelle/Lean. OTOH, Lean is **not** a metalogical framework: it's just a theorem prover built atop CoC.

Comment: @user56834 Understandably, this doesn't answer the question, "But, why?" Well, if you are familiar with logical frameworks (if not, see [(1)](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/gdp/publications/Framework_Def_Log.pdf), [(2)](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/papers/mdorf01.pdf), [(3)](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/papers/handbook01.pdf)), then a natural question is, "Can I do more than just _describe_ and _prove results about_ a deductive system? Can I use it to reason _within_ a deductive system?" A logical framework alone cannot do it. We need more!

Comment: But why are there multiple arrows? That's like asking, "Why does French have the verb _être_ when we already have 'to be' in English?" Well, English is the metalanguage, French is the object language; just as `==>` is the implication in the metalanguage, the object language has its own arrows...because arrows are useful.

Comment: I see. I think then my question becomes, why is it helpful to separate constructs like arrows for the object and meta-language respectively in a theorem prover (given that e.g. Lean works without it)? But perhaps this should be a different post.

Comment: @user56834 You might want to look at the linked references in one of my comments above, to read further about logical frameworks. But it _sounds_ like you're uncertain about the usefulness of a metalanguage _in general_.

Comment: Well I see the usefulness of a meta language when your goal is to prove things about the object level language itself, rather than prove correctness of specific object-level claims. E.g. if we want to prove things about whether a specific object-level language is complete. But if we just want to use a theorem prover to prove facts about a program or a mathematical construct, then I don't see the use of a metalanguage yet.

Comment: @user56834 What about a metalinguistic toolkit to **make** a theorem prover?

Comment: Is that what Isabelle is? Is Isabelle/HOL essentially a package written in Isabelle? If that is so, then I think I get it. At least I thought Isabelle itself was a theorem prover (and I never really got why the /HOL part was separate). (although actually that would still be consistent with unifying --> and => into a single object-level arrow, using the CH correspondence, while having a separate ==> arrow)

Comment: @user56834 Isabelle/HOL is a "package", per se; but Isabelle **is** a theorem prover **and** a toolkit. You prove properties about Isabelle/HOL using Isabelle, and reason within HOL using Isabelle/HOL. It's pretty trippy/deep!

Comment: @user56834 There is also Isabelle/ZF, and more generally for any deductive system X there could be a Isabelle/X "package".